# PHP + Image Editing a image with special symbols

Tags: php

I've been trying to edit a image and add ² into it, I've tried various different ways on uncle google for combating the issue however I'm just competely stuck, the following code is:

```
header("Content-type: image/png; charset=UTF-8");
define('CHARSET', 'ISO-8859-1');
define('REPLACE_FLAGS', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_XHTML);

function html($string) {
    return htmlspecialchars($string, REPLACE_FLAGS, CHARSET);
}
$string = 'Special symbol: ²';
$string = html($string);
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("imgURL");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 209, 209, 209);
$top = 60;
$bot = 160;
$size = 100;
imagestring($im, $size, $top, $bot, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The gd font you are using doesn't have that unicode character - but if you try [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/imagettftext) with a TTF font that does, it should appear on the image.

Comment: @drew010 Thank you! Feel free to submit it as a answer.